# How to select two items from two tables, quantity depends on one item?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: Album and Photo.

When searching with username, I want to get all Album.title and only ONE Photo.url for each album as album cover(doesn't matter which photo).

But if I do :

```
 SELECT Album.title,Photo.url FROM Photo     
 INNER JOIN Contain ON (Photo.picid = Contain.picid)
 INNER JOIN Album ON (Album.albumid = Contain.albumid)
 WHERE username ='david'
```

(Contain is just a relationship table, keeping which album the photo belong to, username is a attribute of Album table)

This returns all the Photo.url but I just want one.. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to group by album.title and use an aggregate function for photo.url

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query:

```
SELECT Album.title,(SELECT Photo.url FROM Photo 
                    WHERE Photo.picid = Contain.picid LIMIT 1) 
 FROM Contain INNER JOIN Album ON (Album.albumid = Contain.albumid)
 WHERE username ='david'
```

Comment: For given title, there will be one photo url which is done by LIMIT 1...Can you provide some data?

Answer (score 0):

you could add a limit 1 to the query,

```
SELECT Album.title,Photo.url FROM Photo LIMIT 1    
INNER JOIN Contain ON (Photo.picid = Contain.picid)
INNER JOIN Album ON (Album.albumid = Contain.albumid)
WHERE username ='david'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to apply group by

```
SELECT Album.title,Photo.url FROM Photo     
INNER JOIN Contain ON (Photo.picid = Contain.picid)
INNER JOIN Album ON (Album.albumid = Contain.albumid)
WHERE username ='david'
Group by Album.title,Photo.url
```